# How do I write a script to download Google app engine data store to a google cloud bucket?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to write a python shell script that will backup our data store. I have read much of the available documentation on the google site, but I still have some questions.

1. What is the address of our data store? Is it a bucket?
2. How do I access this with a command line tool? gsutil? gcloud?

I am imagining something like:
gsutil cp gs//[google app engine data store] gs//[my backup bucket]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, the data stored in Google Datastore is in a database form. Also the current method to export that data is provided as a user interface on the Datastore page, so not sure if a script will even work.

In simple steps:

- Choose the dataset you want to take the backup of
- Provide a bucket location where you want to dump the data
- Edit any parameters for dump file

Your dump will be available at the bucket location that you can later download or import into a new database.

Read More: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/datastoreadmin#backup_and_restore_data

Answer (score 0):

*"Is it a bucket?"*

No.
It's more like a stadium full of cups.  Seriously--it's a highly distributed and redundant network storage solution.  The only way to "hit the backup button" (I won't judge you) is to read everything.

The datastore really isn't a place you should expect to perform system-wide backup/restore on.  Especially if your data gets big.  **I suggest persisting your data to an additional place *at the time of creation* if you're really worried about saving it off.**  I use MySQL (a.k.a. Cloud SQL) and datastore in conjunction sometimes.  The MySQL is an archival place for me while the datastore is quick/fast hot and current data only platform.

Comment: No I meant that I was trying to backup my personal datastore to the cloud. I was in a state of transition between my own storage solution and shifting to the cloud. Also, it was more for version control. Sorry for not clarifying this confusion earlier.